# Where do I find the Pinterest sandbox TAG ID?

Tags: sandbox, pinterest

I'm implementing the **Pinterest Conversion**.

I want to use the **sandbox** to be sure everything is working fine, but I can't find anything on how to generate a **sandbox** id.

Helping links:

- https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/install-the-pinterest-tag
- https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/tag/conversion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your analytics overview (https://analytics.pinterest.com/overview).
There you'll have the option to check the Tag ID. It will be on the top menu, like the screenshot below:

[image: Dashboard]